# Google is indexing both the AMP and Canonical version of a page. Is this normal?

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing, amp

Looking at the results for a branded search I saw Google was listing a page and directly below this the amp version was appearing. Is this normal? I thought Google would list one of the other.

Comment: Sounds like you might be logged into Google, go cookie-less and then test.